# Detectar quando um novo arquivo foi criado

Tags: jquery, c, ajax, json

**Detalhes:** Tenho uma aplicação onde:

1. Tenho uma requisição AJAX com JQuery acionada todas as vezes que
   novos usuários são inseridos passando os dados necessários para um
   arquivo PHP que os recebe via POST e cria um arquivo JSON com estes
   dados.
2. Os dados do arquivo JSON, serão interpretados com linguagem C usando
   [libjson](https://github.com/vincenthz/libjson) para que depois sejam armazenados no banco de dados
   sqlite.

**Pergunta:** Como fazer com que a linguagem C fique "esperando" *e crie um aviso* quando este novo arquivo for gerado para que uma outra função C possa pegá-lo automaticamente e jogar no segundo processo?

Comment: Em linguagem C nao podes fazer isso **eficientemente**. O que podes fazer 'e usar outros mecanismos de deteccao de ficheiro novo e, com esses mecanismos, executar um programa compilado de C. Acho que a tua melhor solucao passa por fazeres o PHP que recebe o POST executar o programa pre-compilado.

Comment: caso você esteja no Linux, isso pode te ajudar: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692134/continuously-monitor-a-directory-in-linux-and-notify-when-a-new-file-is-availabl) ou (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files)

Comment: Porque o banco de dados tem que ser acessado com a linguagem C?

Comment: @MYS, o site também está sendo escrito em linguagem C com auxílio do Mongoose, o banco de dados também. (A linguagem é uma exigência de quem solicitou o projeto pela sua eficiência quando se trata de softwares embarcados)

Answer (score 2):

Vou assumir que você está lidando com ambiente **linux**. Aqui tem uma implementação muito interessante para esse problema: [File Events Notification](https://blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification)

Basicamente uma `thread` é criada para monitorar um diretório enquanto um processo fica rodando mantendo-a viva. Repare que a `thread` pode "ouvir" vários estados diferentes. Sendo estes:

- FILE_ACCESS: Arquivo/Diretório monitorado foi acessado
- FILE_MODIFIED: Arquivo/Diretório monitorado foi modificado
- FILE_ATTRIB: Arquivo/Diretório monitorado teve um atributo alterado
- FILE_NOFOLLOW: Não seguir links simnólicos
- FILE_DELETE: Arquivo/Diretório foi deletado
- FILE_RENAME_TO: Arquivo/Diretório foi renomeado
- FILE_RENAME_FROM: Arquivo/Diretório foi renomeado
- UNMOUNTED: Arquivo/Diretório foi desmontado
- MOUNTEDOVER: Arquivo/Diretório foi montado

Acredito que esses eventos já resolvem seu caso. No código o tratamento para cada evento foi via `if` e `else`, mas sugiro que se crie um `switch` para facilitar a manutenibilidade.

Comment: Rhuan Karlus, interessante: não conhecia esta biblioteca (+1). Vou espreitar.

Answer (score 1):

**Se for em linux**: nestas situações eu costumo usar a biblioteca inotify. Existe interface inotify para várias linguagens de programação. (ver `man inotify` para obter informação sobre o interface C).

Abaixo, segue um exemplo em Perl que fica à espera que alguém crie um ficheiro na pasta "Dir" e chama um comando (por exemplo o teu programa que arruma na base de dados) quando isso acontece.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use Linux::Inotify2;

 my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2 or die "unable to inotify: $!";

 $inotify->watch ("Dir", IN_CREATE, # ... IN_MODIFY,
    sub { my $e = shift;
          my $name = $e->fullname;
          system("ls -la '$name'");             ##  ==> chamar o teu programa C
          print "$name was created\n" if $e->IN_CREATE; }
    );

 1 while $inotify->poll;
```